# How to add a date field to app settings like settings' date/time

Tags: iphone, xcode, date, settings, appsettings

Is there any way to put a date or time field to app settings (plist) for iPhone? I looked through but there is no date typed field there.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solution is to convert the date/time into NSString or NSNumber and then save it to pList.

Comment: I want it too look like standart date/time picker. So this is not the answer I want.